# aspnet core register service with type parameter

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm working on a web app with aspnet core 1.1
I made a class to send some message from the api (controller methods) to a rabbitmq server, something like this

```cs
public interface IRabbitMqAccessLayer<TCaller> where TCaller : class
{
    bool SendMessage(string message);
}

public class RabbitMqAccessLayer<TCaller>: IRabbitMqAccessLayer<TCaller> where TCaller : class 
{
    // some internal variables

    public RabbitMqAccessLayer(IConfigurationRoot config, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        // class initialization
    }

    public bool SendMessage(string message)
    {
        // send the message
    }
}
```

`TCaller` is the class (controller) using the service (just like you use a logger)

```cs
public class TestController: Controller
{
    private readonly IRabbitMqAccessLayer<TestController> _rabbit;

    public TestController(IRabbitMqAccessLayer<TestController> rabbit)
    {
        _rabbit = rabbit;
    }

    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        _rabbit.SendMessage("some message");
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The problem (or, better, my fault) is i don't know hot to correctly configure the service in application startup

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // some services
    services.AddSingleton<IRabbitMqAccessLayer, RabbitMqAccessLayer>(); // <-- ERROR
    // some other services
}
```

This gives me an error `[CS0305] Using the generic type 'IRabbitMqAccessLayer<TCaller>' requires 1 type argument`, which makes sense because the class needs a caller, but how can i specify it in registration (because obviously caller class vary for every controller)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self answer the question, maybe this will help others:

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IRabbitMqAccessLayer<>), typeof(RabbitMqAccessLayer<>));
```